# Pandas: drop_duplicates().fillna(0) not filling zeroes

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates, nan

I'm trying to drop duplicates from a series and then fill the NaNs with 0.  Should be pretty straightforward, but when I chain the two functions together, I still get `NaN` where I would expect `0.0`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,1,2,3,3,4], 'b':[10,20,30,40,50,60]})
df['a'] = df['a'].drop_duplicates().fillna(0)
```

yields:

```
     a   b
0  1.0  10
1  NaN  20
2  2.0  30
3  3.0  40
4  NaN  50
5  4.0  60
```

Whereas:

```
df['a'] = df['a'].drop_duplicates()
df['a'] = df['a'].fillna(0)
```

works fine, but seems unnecessarily verbose.

I'm on pandas 0.20.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is problem after `drop_duplicates` some values are removed and aligning create `NaN`s values. So `reindex` help here:

```
df['a'] = df['a'].drop_duplicates().reindex(df.index, fill_value=0)
print (df)
   a   b
0  1  10
1  0  20
2  2  30
3  3  40
4  0  50
5  4  60
```

Or use [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) with `loc`:

```
df.loc[df['a'].duplicated(), 'a'] = 0
print (df)
   a   b
0  1  10
1  0  20
2  2  30
3  3  40
4  0  50
5  4  60
```

Comment: Or alternately: `df['a'] = df['a'].drop_duplicates().reindex(df.index).fillna(0)`.  thanks @jezrael!

Answer (score 3):

Because `drop_duplicates` removes elements, your result is of smaller size than the dataframe you're assigning back to. This causes index mismatches.

Alternatively, use `mask`/`where` with `duplicated` -

```
df['a'] = df['a'].mask(df['a'].duplicated(), 0)
```

Or,

```
df['a'] = df['a'].where(~df['a'].duplicated(), 0)
```

```
df

   a   b
0  1  10
1  0  20
2  2  30
3  3  40
4  0  50
5  4  60
```

Comment: I like the approach, different than what I would normally use, but good food for thought, thanks @COLDSPEED.

Comment: @pshep123 You're welcome! Also, my second line of code had a typo, sorry about that.